# How to make the content div scrollable without using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple page. Here i want a fixed header and a fixed footer and the body of the content to be scrollable.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">This is Header</div>
    <div class="body">This is Body
        <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body
    <br/>This is Body</div>
    <div class="footer">This is Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #DDD;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.body {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

However when i scroll, the whole page tends to scroll, making my header and footer move.
I can resolve this using javascript, getting the height of the screen and subtracting the header and footer height.

But is there any way we can achieve this only using css. If yes then how ?

Comment: confused with your question.... what you want to do?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/MXDgM/

Comment: Yes to some extend like that, but without position: fixed.

Comment: And 1 more point just need to make the div scrollable not the whole page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple, just make changes as like this

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/rCV6E/1/

Comment: Yes but make have some impact on the smoothness.

Comment: you can watch this to improve the smoothness http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSoRsM5-4Z4

Answer (score 0):

try to use css as:

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

Set overflow to `scroll` and `.header`, `.footer` position to `fixed`.